# Is there a way to "contain" a program so upon alt-tabbing, that program won't stay in front

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

I have a production program that doesn't play well with alt-tabbing. It has multiple child windows like photoshop and alt-tabbing will only switch out the background windows but all the child windows will stay in front. Imagine switching to excel from Photoshop but all the photoshop's layer windows or paint brush windows were still in front. If I click that program's icon on the taskbar, all of its windows minimize. However mouse click is rather slow.

I could move the program to a new desktop (workspace in linux word) so it doesn't interfere with other programs but windows 10's desktop shortcut isn't particularly easy. The sequence would be Win+Tab > Tab > Left or Right > Enter. That's way too many keystroke to switch a program.

Is there anyway I can contain all of that program's child windows in a window so when I alt-tab, they don't stay in front? Or is there a way to quickly switch between windows' desktop eg. Win+1, Win+2, etc.

Comment: Within the System Internals Suite (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite) there is a Application called Desktops which allows you to setup up to 4 Virtual Desktop (Like the Linux Workspaces you mentioned) i‘m not 100% shure on that but i tought it is also possible to assign a Keyboard Short cut to switch between those Virtual Desktops

Comment: I'll research into the shortcut for those. Maybe with autohotkey as a final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it inside a virtual machine, perhaps?

The short answer is "not without help". If the application is written in such a way that there are multiple discrete windows that are not related in the OS as belonging to the same application in the way ALT-TAB handles, then the only way to accomplish this is by re-writing the application (hard, but probably the best solution) or by containing the application within another application that works as the "window" the OS (and ALT-TAB) handles.

Running the application inside a VM may cause difficulties with copy/paste, if that is a necessary part of the application function, though that is not insurmountable. Also, you would have to switch OUT of the VM in order to ALT-TAB, but that would only be a single mouse-click or whatever keyboard shortcut works for the chosen hypervisor, which, even combined with ALT-TAB, would still be less than the workspaces solution you're currently hoping to avoid.

Comment: Understand. Windows desktop (workspace) actually is a pretty good "container" but sadly it is not easy to switch around with the default keybinds. For VM, yes, copy/paste and alt tab is important.

Comment: Another option may be changing keybinds using something like AutoHotkey?

Comment: I found https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer